# Pandas lag using another column for window

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I know that pandas shift method can create a lagged column but all the implementations use static input of a specific number.

How can I create a lagged column using another column as the shift parameter?

```
Date, YTD, Quarter Days, QTD
2023/7/26, 1,000, 26, 200
2023/7/25, 950, 25, 150
…
2023/7/1, 800, 1, 50
```

In the example above, we want to use “Quarter Days” and “YTD” to calculate “QTD”

e.g. `shift(column2)`

Comment: Can you give an example of input / expected output?

Comment: Column 1 is date. Column 2 is a rolling sum YTD. Column 3 and 4 is days since start of quarter and month respectively. 

I want to create a column 5 and 6 that are incremental since start of quarter and month using the date difference in columns 3 and 4

Comment: It would be best to [edit] the question with an explicit (and reproducible) example. See if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76782403/16343464) is what you want.

Comment: How do you get 50? I'd expect 0 Or maybe the shift should have been 25/24 instead of 26/25?

Answer (score 0):

##### updated answer

Subtract the days and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the value for subtraction:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=False)

df['QTD'] = (df['Date']
 .sub(pd.to_timedelta(df['Quarter Days']-1, unit='D'))
 .map(df.set_index('Date')['YTD']).rsub(df['YTD'])
)
```

Output:

```
        Date   YTD  Quarter Days  QTD
0 2023-07-26  1000            26  200
1 2023-07-25   950            25  150
2 2023-07-01   800             1    0
```

##### original answer

What you want is not fully clear, but assuming you want to shift each value using the value of another column as period, you would have to use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

def cust_shift(s1, s2):
    a = s1.to_numpy()
    idx = np.arange(s1.shape[0]) - s2
    return np.where((idx>=0) & (idx<s1.shape[0]),
                    a[np.clip(idx, 0, s1.shape[0]-1)],
                    np.nan)

df['col3'] = cust_shift(df['col1'], df['col2'])
```

Example:

```
  col1  col2 col3
0    A     0    A
1    B     1    A
2    C     4  NaN
3    D     2    B
4    E     3    B
5    F    -2    H
6    G    -1    H
7    H     0    H
8    I   100  NaN
```